# Structure As constructor parameter (Declared in main)

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

I have the following structure declared in main **(NEVERMIND THE MEMBERS!)** :

```
struct args
{
    std::vector<string> names;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<RegularExpression>>vreg;
    std::vector<string> stopFile;
    std::vector<string> groundTruth;
    int debug;
};
```

---

and I have a classe Verification that takes args as a constructor parameter

```
#ifndef VERIFICATION_H
#define VERIFICATION_H

class Verification
{
    public:
        Verification(std::string, std::vector<double>,double,args);
    private:
         args _A; 

}
#endif // VERIFICATION_H
```

---

Now in main:

```
struct args
    {
        std::vector<string> names;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<RegularExpression>>vreg;
        std::vector<string> stopFile;
        std::vector<string> groundTruth;
        int debug;
    };
    int main()
    {
      Verification v("res.cr",gt, 0.75,A);
      return 0;
    }
```

---

I have the following compile errors :

1. Verification.h|33|error: 'args' does not name a type|  **(this error is for the private member in the class _A)**
2. main.cpp|153|error: no matching function for call to 'Verification::Verification(const char [7], std::vector&, double, args&)'|
3. Verification.h|24|error: 'args' has not been declared|**(this error is the constructor)**

How can I use the structure declared in main as a constructor parameter in class verification?

Thank you.

Comment: Off-topic, but you shouldn't use [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) like `_A`.

Comment: Oh yeah? And stupid me I thought that i was doing the right thing lol. I had an inverview with a french company and in their code they did the same as I. 

I even asked them Why don't you have a constructor and a copy constructor, it's the rule of thumb in c++.

She answered: NAAAAAAAAAAAAAA we don't need it. KILL ME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure must be defined in a way that it is visible to the Verification class translation unit.  I suggest you move the struct to its own header file, and #include that in your main file and in Verification.h.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is that when compiling `class Verification` the compiler must see `struct args` *first*. It doesn't know that you are gonig to define `struct args` later.

Simple fix would be to move the definition of `struct args` into `Verification.h`.

Fix that and you'll still have other errors though (most obviously that there's no definition for `A`), but we can deal with those when you get to them.

Answer (score 1):

Your second error is due to the fact that a string literal is a `const char[]`, not a `std::string`- you need to create a `string` before passing it to a function expecting a string.

Also, `gt` and `A` need to be defined before this call.